# How to make SSIS to handle mal-formated csv file?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

As per our project requirements I am migrating DTSs in SQLserver 2000 server into SSISs in SQL server 2008 R2. Now The DTS is absolutely working fine with the following Csv file.

> Col1;Col2;Col2;Col41;Col5;Col6;Col71;Col8;Col9;Col10;Col11,
>   ;Val1,
>   ;Val2,
>   ;Val3,
>   ;Val4,
>   ;Val5,
>   ;Val6,
>   ;Val7,
>   ;Val8,
>   ;Val9,
>   ;Val10,
>   ;Val11,
>   ;Val12,
>   ;Val13,
>   ;Val14,

However SSIS is not working fine and it is giving problem

The DTS converting flat file into Table as shown below Image
[image: Table View in SQL Server 2000]

In SSIS it is converting as shown below Image
[image: Table View in SQL server 2008 R2]

How to resolve this issue? We can not change the format of the csv file as it is generated by some third party services. We have to fix this issue at SSIS end.

Comment: It is not showing Images that I have added to this post. I request some body please help.

Comment: Just click  `Edit` and  change the location for the images.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46285/how-to-add-image-to-so

Comment: It seems that the SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 R2 versions expect a column delimiter for every column, even if it has no value. SQL Server 2000 was a bit more forgiving with this.